# Good features / algorithms for recognizing car-models in images

Tags: computer-vision, local-features, object-recognition

I have a question concerning object recognition, especially recognizing car-models! I am at the beginning of a work about identifying the same car-model in different images. At the moment I think one of the best algorithm for 3D object recognition is SIFT but after playing around a bit with a demo implementation I have the strange feeling this algorithm has some problems with shiny metal objects like cars, especially if they have different colors.

Does anyone know some work on this area in general some suitable algorithm for the task of finding the same car-model in different images?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you post some example images?

Comment: Sure. Images for creating a model of car-models ;-) could be like: [s5 coupe training 1](http://i.imgur.com/FStpV.jpg) or like [s5 coupe training 2](http://i.imgur.com/imgPR.jpg) but also 'normal' pictures. Query images could be like [s5 coupe query 1](http://i.imgur.com/igU4Q.jpg) hope that  helps!

Comment: What alternative Feature-Detectors like SIFT, GLOH or SURF are there to identify suitable key-points on cars?

Comment: @jstr if you ended up implementing the scheme described below, how well did it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would have a look at the so called "bag of words" or "visual words" approach. It is increasingly used for image categorization and identification. This algorithm usually starts by detecting robust points, such as SIFT points, in an image. The region around these found points (the 128 bit SIFT descriptor in your case) is used.

In the most simple form, one can collect all data from all descriptors from all images and cluster them, for example using k-means. Every original image then has descriptors that contribute to a number of clusters. The centroids of these clusters, i.e. the visual words, can be used as a new descriptor for the image.  Basically you hope that the clusters an image its descriptors contribute to, is indicative of the image category.

Again, in the most simple case, you have a list of clusters, and per image, you count which of these clusters contained descriptors from that image and how many. This is similar to the Term Frequency/ Inverse Document Frequency (TD/IFD) method used in text retrieval. See this quick and dirty [Matlab](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24263410/visualwords_demo.m) script.

This approach is actively researched and there are many much more advanced algorithms around.

The VLfeat website contains a nice more advanced [demo](http://www.vlfeat.org/applications/apps.html#apps.caltech-101) of this approach, classifying the caltech 101 dataset.  Also noteworthy, are results and software from [Caltech](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/malaa/software/research/image-search/) itself.

Comment: Hey Maurits, thank you for your answer. I'll think about that! But one question. If I have the 'visual words' how do I measure the distance between them? I think I would use the SIFT descriptors is that correct?

- Lowe has one paper in which he describes a method for recognizing 3D objects by building up models of SIFT descriptors. Does anyone know some good other papers on this topic (3D object recognition with other features)?

Comment: In this case, just the euclidean distance, as you are clustering integer vectors. I don't think you have to measure the distance between cluster centroids per se, but rather, when presented with a query image (and thus query descriptors) you measure to which centroids these descriptors are the most closest.

Comment: Ok using a distance measure is clear ;-) but on which data? On the SIFT Descriptors per visual word?

Comment: Three times in fact, as a metric for the initial clustering, to ascertain to which centroid/visualword a query descriptor is the most close, and then finally, to compare the query td/idf vector against the ones in the database.

Comment: Ok I got that ;-) but on which data does the distance measure work? On the SIFT descriptors?

Comment: On the descriptors ( to cluster them), the descriptors vs the centroids ( to build tf/idf vectors) and on thetf/idf vectors (to match a query tf/idf vector against the others). Have a look at the small matlab script I linked to.

Comment: Hey Maurits, thank you :-) I got it, was a little confused about that!

Comment: You are welcome, good luck!